# How to run ExtJS in Cypress testing?

Tags: testing, extjs, cypress

Is there a way to inject ExtJS library inside Cypress testing environment?

For example, I have a grid with `itemID: 'something'` and I would like to fetch it in a test using `Ext.down('#something');`

Currently I get an error that

> Ext is not defined

Is there a way to include it?

In the project ExtJS is added using `<script>` tag in index.html

Comment: Most probably Ext is not loaded yet at the time the spec starts. Try waiting for it to be available in your spec